# Replace substring with some math characters from String - java

Tags: java, regex, special-characters, replaceall

I have a math expression looks like `String st = "((3-(5-2))+(2*(5-1)))";` and I want to `replaceAll` (5-1) with 4 and after that `replaceAll` (2*4) with 8 and... I haven't problem with replacing (5-1) with 4 but when I received to (2*4), as it has * star sign this code ( `st.replaceAll("(2*4)", 8);` ) doesn't work!

Could you help me to `replaceAll` expression that contains special characters.

Comment: `escape the *`.....its a quantifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to attach `"\"` before `"*"` , for using in java, use one more `"\"`.

Also need to escape braces.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st = "((3-(5-2))+(2*(5-1)))";
        st = st.replaceAll("(5-1)", "4");
        System.out.println(st);
        st = st.replaceAll("(2\\*\\(4\\))", "8");
        System.out.println(st);
    }
```

**Output**

```
((3-(5-2))+(2*(4)))

((3-(5-2))+(8))
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why do you want to use a replaceAll() try replace() instead.

Because replaceAll() takes a regex and * becomes a quantifier.

```
String st = "((3-(5-2))+(2*(5-1)))";

st = st.replace("(5-1)", "4");
st = st.replace("(2*4)", "8");
System.out.println(st);
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression so you need to escape the `*` with `\`.

Because you are in java, you need to escape the `\` from the regular expression too